# Optimising buffer allocation in a shared buffer (with total max capacity)

Tags: optimization, queueing-theory

My intention is to optimise buffer allocation in a shared buffer (with total max capacity) where each incoming and outgoing  packet  belongs to a category (we have a finite number of categories < total buffer size), and the packets are inserted and removed so that each category has a different and independent input and output rate following FIFO scheme. Also we want to minimise packet drops.

For further clarification, suppose that my total buffer size is 100, and I have categories {A, B, C}, each packet belongs to any one of these categories, and each category packet has a variable insertion and removal rate from the buffer. I want to dynamically assign an upper-limit on each category packets that the buffer can hold so throughput is maximised and packet drop is minimised. Here we cannot change the insertion rate, for removal if there exists no packet for a category A then removal request for A will do nothing but a remove(A) polling will still take place on the buffer regardless of it having a packet or not.

It would be sufficient even if I get a hint of what approach I should follow. I may not have explained my problem clearly, please comment for any further clarifications.